# Create a StackNavigator within a SwitchNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a createSwitchNavigator that takes me through the welcomescreen to a main Dashboard. This dashboard contains a createBottomTabNavigator (Home, AddImage, Settings). However, i'd like the routname headers for each to appear at the top. When creating my AppSwitchNavigator, it wont seem to accept the DashboardStackNavigator. Any idea why?

```
class WelcomeScreen extends Component {} .....

class DashboardScreen extends Component{}......

class Home extends Component{}......

class AddImage extends Component{}......

class Settings extends Component{}......


//Tabs across the bottom of the screen

const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(

{

   Home, //defined in the above

   AddImage, //defined in the above

   Settings //defined in the above

},

)



const DashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

   DashboardTabNavigator: DashboardTabNavigator

})



const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({

     Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },

     Dashboard: { screen: DashboardStackNavigator }   

 })



const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

//Export App

export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{   
   Home: createStackNavigator({ Home }),
   AddImage: createStackNavigator({ AddImage }),
   Settings: createStackNavigator({ Settings }),
},
```

## Why?

Navigation Header is used in StackNavigator. Thus, using StackNavigator Components in each tabs is simple and right way.

Comment: This seems to return the same error as when using { screen: DashboardStackNavigator } insode the AppSwitchNavigator. It returns error Cannot read property 'State' of undefined.

Comment: @chai86 You need to write exactly what messages you've got.It is a totally different between getting error and not work well. Why do not say about error when you ask first?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that naming one of the routes `Home` was the cause. Once I renamed the key to `HomeScreen`, it worked just fine.

It seems like `Home` is a reserved keyword of some sort in react-navigation that's not documented properly.